# Как загрузить скрипты и стили WooCommerce только на его страницах?

Tags: wordpress

Пробовал след.код

```
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_manage_woocommerce_styles', 99 );

function child_manage_woocommerce_styles() {

    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $GLOBALS['woocommerce'], 'generator' ) );


    if ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) ) {

        if ( ! is_woocommerce() && ! is_cart() && ! is_checkout() ) {
            wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_frontend_styles' );
            wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_fancybox_styles' );
            wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_chosen_styles' );
            wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_prettyPhoto_css' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'wc_price_slider' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart-fragments' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-chosen' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'woocommerce' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto-init' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-blockui' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-placeholder' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'fancybox' );
            wp_dequeue_script( 'jqueryui' );
        }
    }

}
```

но что-то не помогло. Что посоветуете? Версия WordPress 4.9.10
ПОМОГ ВОТ ЭТОТ код:

```
add_action( 'wp', function () {

   $status = is_woocommerce() || is_cart() || is_checkout();

   if (! $status ) {
      remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ 'WC_Frontend_Scripts', 'load_scripts' ] );
      remove_action( 'wp_print_scripts', [ 'WC_Frontend_Scripts', 'localize_printed_scripts' ], 5 );
      remove_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', [ 'WC_Frontend_Scripts', 'localize_printed_scripts' ], 5 );

   }

} );
```

Comment: Вы взяли кусок с гитхаба. Там все правильно по идее. Вы неправильно вставили. Кэш плагины стоят?

Comment: С этим разобрался, но есть ещё одна проблемка. Как можно с тобой связаться?

Comment: Вы бы не могли привести ваше решение?