# Как отключить выполнение скрипта recaptcha на всех страницах сайта кроме одной

Tags: wordpress

Хочу отключить лишние скрипты на страницах сайта.

убрал по [данной инструкции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995385/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-woocommerce-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%85/1028002#1028002) вукомерсовские скрипты

хотел еще рекаптчу от гугла убрать только для страницы регистрации, но так и нне смог разобраться.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста

Comment: Нужно знать, каким образом рекапча подключается на страницы

Comment: Капча подключена через плагин для ВП - Profile Builder. Пытался найти нужный handle для капчи, чтобы ее отрубить через wp_deregister_script. но не смог.